# Php code for display 10 records from mysql dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have MySql Table with 25 rows and i want to display first 10 rows in a page using PHP.. When i Click the next button it shows another 10 rows from table and so on...Help Me.
Thank you..

Comment: Google for "pagination in php"

Comment: Unless dealing with large result sets, or data that is continously extended, the overhead of making the round trip to the db is likely to be larger than just stuffing the whole result into an array/json/xml, and handling the pagination entirely in php/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Pagination code is as below.

Try it.

```
<?php

    include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.
    $tbl_name="";       //your table name
    $adjacents = 3;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];


    $targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">? previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">? previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next ?</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next ?</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";     
    }
?>

    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        // Your while loop here

        }
    ?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

Comment: Please no example with `mysql_*`. Add an `i` atleast.

Answer (score 3):

Very broad question, but the basics are it can be solved with the "LIMIT" MySQL command.  Basically your PHP code detects if someone has gone to another page and then when it makes it's query, the "LIMIT" is adjusted.  So for page 1, the "LIMIT" in this MySQL pseudocode would be:

```
SELECT * FROM {my table} WHERE {criteria is this} LIMIT 0,10
```

And for page 2 the "LIMIT" would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM {my table} WHERE {criteria is this} LIMIT 11,20
```

As for the PHP pagination, you would have to come up with some logic.  Perhaps—and most traditionally—passing a URL variable via POST such as:

```
http://localhost/index.php?pn=2
```

Then your PHP logic does some math to determine the start & end of the range.  So in this example maybe do something like:

```
$pn = $GET['pn'];
$per_page = 10;
$bottom_limit = (($pn*$per_page)-$per_page)+1);
$top_limit = ($pn*$per_page);
```

And then in PHP the LIMIT would be placed along the lines of:

```
$limit = " LIMIT " . $bottom_limit . ", " . $top_limit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LIMIT Statement in your query....
you need to use pagination with Php..

Comment: but you don't need to use limit :-)

Comment: But most often use LIMIT clause in the query when dealing with pagination